# Client Basic Authentication and Web API

Tags: authentication, ssl, webapi

Having figured out how basic authentication in Web API works with SSL, I want to do the following:

After the client is authenticated, send the client a token (right now I am thinking that this should just be GUID) with some expiry date, after which the token would render useless and the client will have to authenticate again.

My problem is knowing how the client would send this token in subsequent requests? Should it be sent in:

```
 a) JSON payload or 
 b) part of header
```

If a) then how about GET requests that do not have a body and therefore no JSON payload?
If  b) then what should it be called in the header... or I can just call it anything? Like, `authToken: Asdhad-asdlad-82hjf-adkga`?

Also, since I am using SSL, I do not know if its better to use token or just use user credentials?

Enlighten me on what the standard is here or am I going in the wrong direction?

Answer (score 0):

put the token in the authorization header and name it: "bearer ej304305340Mytoken". SSL is used for authentication of user + password and the subsequent requests with the token.